# Differ style files from module style files

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-5

I'm writing `webpack` config for my `React`/`TypeScript` application. I want to generate unique names for `class`es and `id`s only if file name ending with `.module.scss` or `.module.css`

So I wrote these rules:

```
{
    test: /\.module\.s?css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                modules: {
                    localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:8]',
                },
            },
        },
        'postcss-loader',
        'sass-loader',
    ],
},
{
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|(\.module\.s?css$))/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'postcss-loader',
        'sass-loader',
    ],
},
```

There are no problems and everything works like I expected but I wonder is there more easy way to do the same thing without a lot of duplication?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, the behavior you describe is the default behavior for css-loader nowadays (was changed same years ago): files that follow the pattern `*.module.(s)css` are treated as css-modules (classnames get hashed) and any other files are not treated as modules.